# Unable to Click using click method (No Exception) as well as not able to switch to parent window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Here is my config:
Windows 7 VM + Selenium Web Driver + IE 11 + IE Driver Server 64 bit

I have a weird problem, where in, when a click event is encountered in code, the execution just suspends and doesn't proceed. I was able to overcome this by using sendKeys(Keys.Enter) instead of click. But i see the same behavior while trying to switch to a popup window and returning back to the parent frame.

This is the code i use for switching to child and returning to parent window :

```
            WebDriver popup = null;
            String popwin = "";
            boolean present;

            try {

                System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

                String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
                for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                    System.out.println("WinHandle : " + winHandle);
                    popwin = winHandle;
                }
                 popup = driver.switchTo().window(popwin);
               Actions action = new Actions(popup); action.moveToElement(popup.findElement(by.id("idContinue")))
                                .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform(); //works fine till above, clicks continue button in popup and the popup closes automatically
             driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

The execution suspends at the last line, the Thread keeps running with no results and no exceptions are thrown.

Thank you!!

Note: The application under test is an IE only compatible system and hence there is no way to test it in other browsers.(the App doesn't even load in other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Is this part of the code executed after the popup is displayed on the screen or before it?

If this is executed after the popup is shown then the line :

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

is getting the instance of the popup, and on closing the pop up by clicking the button you are destroying that instance itself.

So there are 2 solutions to this issues:

1. Place the line : [String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();] before the popup appears on the screen.
2. Modify the present code:

   ```
       WebDriver popup = null;
       String popwin = "";
       boolean present;

       try {

           System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

           for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
               System.out.println("WinHandle : " + winHandle);
               driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
               Actions action = new Actions(popup);
               action.moveToElement(popup.findElement(by.id("idContinue"))).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
               break; 
           }
   ```

These two tricks will surely solve the issue you are facing